# change order of display via css

Tags: css, mobile, layout

I have a piece of bootstrap based code:

```
<div class="alert alert-primary" style="padding:0.6rem;margin-bottom:0.5rem">
  <div style="display:inline-block;font-weight:bold;width:100px;vertical-align:top">Name</div>
  <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top">Summary, which is long and will wrap on small screen</div>
  <div style="display:inline-block;float:right;vertical-align:top">Date</div>
</div>
```

which looks like this on laptop screen:

```
Name    Summary...            Date
```

While on phone screen it looks like:

```
Name
Summary...
                                                    Date
```

i.e. Date is on the 3rd row, and pops out of the background of the "alert" box.

I want it to be this on phone screen:

```
Name                                       Date
Summary, ....
... ...
```

i.e. on large screen:  **name, summary, date**, on small screen, **name, date, summary**.

Is that possible

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

Answer (score -1):

**please try this code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<style>


@media(max-width: 767px){
  .alert.alert-primary{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .alert div:nth-child(1){
    order: 1;
    display: block !important;
  }
  .alert div:nth-child(2){
    order: 3;
    display: block !important;
  }
  .alert div:nth-child(3){
    order: 2;
    display: block !important;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="alert alert-primary" style="padding:0.6rem;margin-bottom:0.5rem">
  <div style="display:inline-block;font-weight:bold;width:100px;vertical-align:top">Name</div>
  <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top">Summary, which is long and will wrap on small screen</div>
  <div style="display:inline-block;float:right;vertical-align:top">Date</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this **almost** worked.  The only problem is that the 3rd child (date field) lost its "float right" property.  The effect on small screen is that the date appears on the 2nd row, instead of on the right of the first row. Also, even I add float:right **!important** in the CSS won't help.